# Best way of representing binary data

Tags: c++, qt

I am writing a Qt C++ application where I am reading a pcap file and interpreting packets described in given file. As I am reading packet by packet, I need to somehow store binary data. It needs to be flexible enough so I can pass it across multiple functions as parameter and being able to work with it as `char*`. It also should be safe enough to avoid memory leaks.

I came up with 2 approaches:

**1. unique_ptr<char[]>**

So basically I can use `std::ifstream` for reading from file and storing binary data in `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` like so :

```cpp
std::ifstream ifs(fullFilename.c_str(), std::fstream::binary | std::fstream::in, _SH_DENYNO);
std::unique_ptr<char[]> buff = std::make_unique<char[]>(65535); //size is set according to pcap_hdr_s.snaplen
ifs.read(buff.get(), 65535);
```

And then passing it to function via raw pointer (`void f(const unsigned char* p) => f((unsigned char*)buff.get()))` or via reference (`void f(std::unique_ptr<char[]>& p) => f(buff)`)

**2. QByteArray**

In this approach, I would use `QFile` for reading from file and storing data in `QByteArray` like this :

```cpp
QFile file(fileName.c_str());
QByteArray buff;
buff.resize(65535);
file.read(buff.data(), 65535);
```

And then passing it to the functions via reference ( `void f(QByteArray& buff) => f(buff)` ).

Which approach is better ? Or do you have some better way of doing this ?

Comment: Always `65535` bytes? How about a `std::array<unsigned char, 65535>`? I would also use `unsigned char` instead of `char` for binary data.

Comment: @mch as i said, "size is set according to pcap_hdr_s.snaplen" which you can find here : https://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat . It usually is 65535, but I'd rather let it be dynamic according to snaplen value.

Comment: Then I would use a `std::vector<unsigned char>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes about Qt:

1. You can use `QByteArray QIODevice::readAll()` directly to obtain a buffer:

   ```
   QFile file(fileName.c_str());
   auto buff = file.readAll();
   ```
2. `QByteArray` is [implicite sharing / copy-on-write](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html). So while you can pass by reference, you should either pass by const reference or simply pass by value.

Your solution with `std::unique_ptr<>` looks like a good thing to do, but also a bit cumbersome. If your project is already heavily using Qt, I would go for the Qt route.

Passing a reference to a `unique_ptr` is also quite unexpected. Either pass the raw pointer/reference (for example to a helper method, that will return while you hold the `unique_ptr`), or by moving the `unique_ptr` (if you want to transfer ownership). See an [explanation here](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rr-smartptrparam).

Comment: Is it generally safe to use `readAll` ? It might be a little dangerous. What if I would like to interpret some big files(in size of MB) ? I think its not a very good idea to have object of that continous size on stack.

Comment: @PeterLakatoš First of all, `QByteArray`, just like other containers (e.g. `QVector`, `std::vector`), stores the data on the heap. Just think about it: otherwise implicit sharing couldn't work. Also, you can just query for the file's size in advance to do a sanity check. Use `qint64 QFile::size() const`. I believe that's a better approach than silently clipping the file contents (ideally, you would have this check anyways as you are expecting an exact file size; even a lesser size would mean there is an error).